# How to generate CSV file from Android Studio Table Layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, export-to-csv, android-tablelayout

I'm developing an android app that stores user input in the SQLite database. and displays it in TableLayout in android studio. Now I want to generate a CSV file from the contents of that Table Layout.

I need a button to generate the CSV file. Thanks in advance.
I'm new to StackOverflow and coding. So forgive me If my question wasn't right.

I really need this code to complete my project. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wel what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html, various ways to connect it up to the results of an sql query

Comment: I cannot generate CSV file from the TableLayout which is being displayed in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample complete project for reading data from Rss-provider insert to database and show on listview then in next activity create a csv file.

In the first activity wait to load data form Rss-provider after showing in list view data stored in DB, then click button to go to next activity for creating Csv list

For creating csv all columns should be separated with comma (,).

**NOTICE**: check in Android below 10

**ManifestFile:** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hafez">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:minSdkVersion="30" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="RssReader"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Hafez">
        <activity
            android:name=".CsvMaker"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RssReader"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**rss_reader.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvRss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/launch_csv_activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Got to csv maker"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvRss" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_csv_maker.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CsvMaker">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/csv_maker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Csv  file"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/csv_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:text="Csv File address comes here after creation"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RssReader.java** :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class RssReader extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvRss;
    ArrayList<String> titles;
    ArrayList<String> links;
    ArrayList<NewsInformation> news =new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private Button csv_launcher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss_reader);
        lvRss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRss);

        csv_launcher = (Button)findViewById(R.id.launch_csv_activity);
        csv_launcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(getBaseContext(),CsvMaker.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        if(isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            new ProcessInBackground().execute();
        } else {
            try {
                db.open();
                ArrayList<NewsInformation> news = db.getAllNews();
                CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,news);
                lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
                db.close();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                throwables.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RssReader.this);

        Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching Latest News!");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            try {
                // rss feed site here
                URL url = new URL("https://moxie.foxnews.com/feedburner/world.xml");

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document doc = db.parse(getInputStream(url));

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                //// fetch every node item in RSS and create news_item list
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    NewsInformation news_item = new NewsInformation();
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    Element parentItem = (Element) node;

                    NodeList links = parentItem.getElementsByTagName("link");
                    Element element_link = (Element) links.item(0);
                    NodeList element_link_childNodes = element_link.getChildNodes();
                    news_item.link = element_link_childNodes.item(0).getNodeValue();

                    NodeList titles = parentItem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    Element element_title = (Element) titles.item(0);
                    NodeList element_title_childNodes = element_title.getChildNodes();
                    news_item.title = element_title_childNodes.item(0).getNodeValue();


                    NodeList pubDates = parentItem.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
                    Element element_pubDate = (Element) pubDates.item(0);
                    NodeList element_pubDate_childNodes = element_pubDate.getChildNodes();
                    news_item.pubdate = element_pubDate_childNodes.item(0).getNodeValue();


                    NodeList description = parentItem.getElementsByTagName("description");
                    Element element_description = (Element) description.item(0);
                    if(element_description !=null){
                        NodeList element_description_childNodes = element_description.getChildNodes();
                        news_item.description = element_description_childNodes.item(0).getNodeValue();
                        Log.e("soheil", news_item.description+"");
                    } else {
                        news_item.description =" ";
                    }

                    NodeList image = parentItem.getElementsByTagName("media:group");
                    Element element_image = (Element) image.item(0);
                    NodeList image_content = element_image.getElementsByTagName("media:content");
                    Element image_content_element = (Element) image_content.item(0);
                    news_item.image = image_content_element.getAttribute("url");

                    news.add(news_item);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                exception = e;
                Log.e("IMAGE:","1");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                exception = e;
                Log.e("IMAGE:","2");
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("IMAGE:","3");
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("IMAGE:","4");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(),news);
            lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);

                try {
                    db.open();
                    for (int i = 0; i < news.size(); ++i) {
                        db.insertNewsInfo(news.get(i));
                    }
                    db.close();

                } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                    throwables.printStackTrace();
                }

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }
}
```

**CsvMaker.java :**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CsvMaker extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<NewsInformation> news = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    Button csv_maker;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_csv_maker);

        csv_maker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.csv_maker);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.csv_address);

        csv_maker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hasStoragePermission(1);
            }
        });


    }

    public void createCsv() {
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        try {
            db.open();
            news = db.getAllNews();
            db.close();
            exportTheDB();

        } catch (SQLException | IOException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();

        }
    }


    private void exportTheDB() throws IOException {
        File myFile;
        try {

            myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(""), "csvFile.csv");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append("News_Description,News_Image,News_link,News_Title");
            myOutWriter.append("\n");


            for (int i = 0; i < news.size(); ++i) {
                String description = news.get(i).description;
                String image = news.get(i).image;
                String link = news.get(i).link;
                String title = news.get(i).title;
                myOutWriter.append(description + "," + image + "," + link + "," + title);
                myOutWriter.append("\n");
                Log.e("soheil", description + "," + image + "," + link + "," + title);
            }


            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            txt.setText(myFile.getAbsolutePath());


        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        }


    }

    private void hasStoragePermission(int requestCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                //  return false;
            } else {
                createCsv();
                // return true;
            }
        } else {
            //return true;
            createCsv();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                createCsv();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java :**

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class DatabaseHandler {
    
        private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase database;
    
    
        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
    
        //methods for all table
        public void open() throws SQLException {
            database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    
        public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    
        public void clearTable(String tableName) {
            database.delete( tableName, null, null);
        }
    
        //news table method
    
        public void insertNewsInfo(NewsInformation newsInfo) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("title"          ,  newsInfo.title );
            cv.put("link"           ,  newsInfo.link );
            cv.put("pubdate"        ,  newsInfo.pubdate );
            cv.put("description"       ,  newsInfo.description );
            cv.put("image"       ,  newsInfo.image );
    
    
            database.insert("news" , "writerName", cv);
        }
    
    
        public ArrayList<NewsInformation> getAllNews() {
            ArrayList<NewsInformation> NewsInfoList = new ArrayList<NewsInformation>();
    
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM  news" ,new String[]{});
    
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                NewsInformation newsInfo = new NewsInformation();
    
                newsInfo.title = cursor.getString(0);
                newsInfo.link = cursor.getString(1);
                newsInfo.pubdate = cursor.getString(2);
                newsInfo.description = cursor.getString(3);
                newsInfo.image = cursor.getString(3);
    
                NewsInfoList.add(newsInfo);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
    
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
    
            return NewsInfoList;
        }
    
        public String getBigBody(String completeBodyLink) {
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select bigBody FROM news where completeTextLink = ?", new String[]{completeBodyLink});
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String bigBody = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            return bigBody;
        }
    }
```

**DatabaseHelper.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_for_news";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 10);

        //fdd
        Log.i(TAG, "Object created.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE news ( " +
                " title TEXT , link TEXT , pubdate TEXT ,description TEXT ," +
                " image TEXT );");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists news" );
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**NewsInformation.java (DataModel) :**

```
    public class NewsInformation
{
    public String link;
    public String title;
    public String pubdate;
    public String description;
    public String image;

}
```

**CustomAdapter.java:**

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsInformation> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsInformation> news) {

        super(context, 0, news);

    }



    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        NewsInformation item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        title.setText(item.title);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.link);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;

    }}
```

Comment: Note this code is not all character safe, better to use apache commons-csv `print` and `println` to replace `myOutWriter.append`

Comment: I cannot get DatabaseHandler in my code it is not listing. When I type it, It shows me an error.

Comment: i created a mini sample and real project for you and edited my answer so check it, connect your device to internet to load data in database and ....,i hope this solve your problem, mark it as correct here for others an give me score too :))